# multiple git commands one line on vs code terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

> git add . && git commit -m "mymsg" && git push

it's doensn't work on my vscode..

error:

> git add . && commit -m "msg" && push -u ori ...
> ~~ The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use semicolon as a separator:

```
git status ; git status
```

Comment: There is a semantic difference between OP's variant and yours.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best option, but you can workaround by choosing the Git Bash shell selector, i.e., specify the exact executable that you want to use in the settings file, for instance:

```py
// Git Bash
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"

// Bash on Ubuntu (on Windows)
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"

// Cygwin
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe"

// Cmder
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\cmder\\Cmder.exe"
```

Take a look at the detailed documentation about [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)